# Closed set on Euclidean space that is not compact

Tags: general-topology

I have read that a subset of Euclidean space may be called compact if it is both closed and bounded.  I was wondering what a good example of a closed but unbounded set would be?

Would a closed ball inside a sphere with an infinite radius do the trick?  If that example works are there any other examples people could think of?

Comment: $[0, \infty)$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The entire space.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Being closed means nothing but being the *complement of an open set*. So take any bounded open subset $S \subset \mathbb R^n$, then $\mathbb R^n \setminus S$ is *closed* but not bounded. What you are looking for.

I.e:, Any complement of any open ball!

Comment: That's exactly the response I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

A simple example of a closed but unbounded set is $[0,\infty)$.